# How to guarantee that a brush in a scatterplot made based in dimension with 3 keys interact with other charts?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

How can I guarantee the multi-chart filter behavior by using three keys in the scatterplots dimensions?

as you can see in [ https://jsfiddle.net/rogeraleite/dmf3fstw/2/ ]
..specific in the lines where I declare the dimensions for the scatterplots:

```
dim1 = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return [+d.x, +d.y, d.fruit];
    //return [+d.x, +d.y];
})
```

If I comment " return [+d.x, +d.y, d.fruit]; " and use " return [+d.x, +d.y]; ", the interactions (brushing) works perfectly. However, once I try to add the third key (d.fruit) in order to color the dots in the chart, the brushing stop working.

Any idea of how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realize that to keep the interaction working I had to use only two keys in the dimension creation. However, to create the group I could use another dimension with more than two keys and it would guarantee the right behavior.

See in https://jsfiddle.net/rogeraleite/L8mjrnr1/ :

```
    dim1 = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return [+d.x, +d.y];
    }),
    dim1_2 = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return [+d.x, +d.y, d.fruit];
    }),
    dim2 = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return [+d.y, +d.z];
    }),
    dim2_2 = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return [+d.y, +d.z, d.fruit];
    }),
    group1 = dim1_2.group(),
    group2 = dim2_2.group();
```

...so when the colorAccessor try to access the third key (d.key[2]), it works! =D

```
.colorAccessor(function(d) { return d.key[2]; })
```